# Can a pointer value change just by passing it to another function?

Tags: c, pointers, gdb

I am debugging my function A with GDB, and just before calling function B, I print the following value:

```
p *(key->s->fds[3].handler)
```

and I get as a result:  (these are all function pointers)

```
$3 = {handle_read = 0x55555555ba49 <socks5_read>, handle_write = 0x55555555baa2 <socks5_write>, handle_block = 0x55555555bb0a <socks5_block>, handle_close = 0x55555555bb15 <socks5_close>}
```

Then, I type `s` to enter function B with GDB.
Immediately after, I print `p *(key->s->fds[3].handler)` again, but its value is:

```
$4 = {handle_read = 0x7fffffffdb90, handle_write = 0x5555baa2, handle_block = 0x55555555bb0a <socks5_block>, handle_close = 0x55555555bb15 <socks5_close>}
```

I know that this question is really open, because I should show some of my code. But my question is general: Is it possible that the contents of my struct change just by passing a pointer to a function?

If it helps, this is the complete trace of what I've done in GDB:

```
(gdb) s
31              stm->current->on_arrival(stm->current->state, key);
(gdb) p *(key->s->fds[3].handler)
$3 = {handle_read = 0x55555555ba49 <socks5_read>, handle_write = 0x55555555baa2 <socks5_write>, handle_block = 0x55555555bb0a <socks5_block>, 
  handle_close = 0x55555555bb15 <socks5_close>}
(gdb) s
hello_read_init (state=0, key=0x7fffffffdb90) at src/stm/stm_hello.c:20
20      hello_stm *hello_stm = &ATTACHMENT(key)->hello_state;
(gdb) p *(key->s->fds[3].handler)
$4 = {handle_read = 0x7fffffffdb90, handle_write = 0x5555baa2, handle_block = 0x55555555bb0a <socks5_block>, 
  handle_close = 0x55555555bb15 <socks5_close>}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Possibilities in my mind are: 1. `key` is representing different things because you entered to a different scope by function call. 2. The structure is modified by another thread. Would you mind posting a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible if you're abusing a pointer to a local variable returned from some function, or otherwise have undefined behaviour in your code.  In fact, if it happens, you should suspect that you have UB somewhere — and find it and fix it.  However, without code, we really can't help you further, which makes this question less than satisfactory for SO.

Comment: "Anything" is possible when you invoke undefined behaviour. One of the involved pointers is probably invalid, pointing to somewhere in the call frame of a function that has returned. `-fsanitize=address` might be of use to you.

Comment: The pointer? No. The thing it points to? Yes. What does it point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that the contents of my struct change just by passing a pointer to a function?

There are 3 possible reasons I can think of (most to least likely):

1. Your program has undefined behavior of the [stack use after scope](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2016-11/Slides/Buka-StackUseAfterScope.pdf) variety.
   That is, if `key->s->fds[3].handler` points to stack of a frame which has already returned, that stack will be overwritten by subsequent call instructions.
2. You didn't `step` far enough.
   If the called function is optimized, it is possible for GDB to stop in `hello_read_init` prolog (area where registers aren't yet set up).
3. You have a multithreaded program and a data race (another thread overwrites `key->s->fds[3].handler->handle_read` while the first thread uses it).

Using Address Sanitizer should show whether this is an instance of UB (the first possibility above) right away.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me identify the problem. It was reason N°1. Thanks everyone who commented my question, it really helped too.

Comment: N°2 was it for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Employed Russian's answers, this can happen if you have stepped into a file in a library with different precompiler defines and you have a "#ifdef XXX" around field(s) in the data you are printing in GDB. I just encountered this case.

For example, say your binary named "test_cmd" has -DDEBUG but your library named "lib_my_cmd" does not have it. And then, your struct is defined as...

```
// my_cmd.h has...
typedef struct {
    #ifdef DEBUG
      int my_debug_only_field;
    #endif
    int my_regular_field;
} my_info;
...
```

```
// my_cmd.c, built as part of lib_my_cmd without -DDEBUG, has...
#include "my_cmd.h"

void do_foo(my_info* inputs) {
    // GDB stepping in here, where DEBUG is not defined, the value of
    //   inputs.my_regular_field is 1.  <== Expected to be 0!!!
}
```

```
// my_foo_test.cc, built in the binary with -DDEBUG, has...
#include "my_cmd.h"

void test_foo() {
    my_info inputs;
    inputs.my_debug_only_field = 1;
    inputs.my_regular_field = 0;
    do_foo(&inputs);
    //...
```

The `inputs` field values change when you step from `test_foo()` into `do_foo(...)`.